# How to redraw whole app with new ThemeData?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 2 `ThemeData` vars and a `SwitchListTile` with the following code:

```
new SwitchListTile(
                      value: applyDarkTheme,
                      title: const Text('Appy dark theme?'),
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState(() {
                          applyDarkTheme = value;
                        });
                      })
```

the `applyDarkTheme` is a variable i check only when creating the app for the first time:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Test Application',
  home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Test app'),
  theme: settings.applyDarkTheme ? AppThemes.dark : AppThemes.light,
  routes: _routes,
);
```

How can i redraw the app with the new `ThemeData` when i change the switch state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider nesting your `MaterialApp` within a StatefulWidget

- [Stateful and Stateless Widgets](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#stateful-stateless)
- [Stateful Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

The Flutter Gallery example app does this in their [GalleryApp](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart) widget.

- Use a simple, light StatefulWidget class e.g. [GalleryApp](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart#L16-L38)
- Which creates the corresponding [GalleryAppState](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart#L40-L41) class.
- This class has the `GalleryTheme _galleryTheme` instance variable
- You need to set/change this value within the [setState()](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart#L83-L85) method [[ref]](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).
- You can then [pass this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart#L163) them to the MaterialApp constructor

Here is a modified snippet

```
class GalleryApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GalleryAppState createState() => new GalleryAppState();
}

class GalleryAppState extends State<GalleryApp> {
  GalleryTheme _galleryTheme = kAllGalleryThemes[0];
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget home = new GalleryHome(
      galleryTheme: _galleryTheme,
      onThemeChanged: (GalleryTheme value) {
        setState(() {
          _galleryTheme = value;
        });
      },
      ...
    );

    ...

    return new MaterialApp(
      ...
      home: home,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!
After a lot of editing i finally made it.